# Complete C++ "from scratch" frameworks

Tags: c++, frameworks, poco

What C++ frameworks provide a complete skeleton, in the fashion of Ruby on Rails?

I think Poco C++ does it, are there other options?

Comment: There is no *magically-does-everything* framework - you might want to give us more specific requirements.

Comment: A complete skeleton for what? Rails provides a skeleton for writing MVC web applications, but it is not a "complete" skeleton for *everything*. What do you need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to provide a skeleton for client applications, because there is no common functionality like in the case of web applications. [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) does a pretty good job at providing what you might need in a new application though (yes, it does much more than just GUI).

Comment: Hi.

How well Qt compares to Poco or other libraries?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used Poco or another all-in-one kind of framework.

Comment: @SyBer: Without specific requirements the answer can only be *"it depends"*

Comment: Hi.

Just looking a good framework to quick-start writing a Linux app.

Guess I will need to try Poco to know for sure.

Comment: I know I'm biased, but I would just go with Qt. It has both low and high level network classes, low and high level threading classes, database support, xml parsing and processing, scripting language, media player, many small utility classes and everything is well integrated with the GUI part (if you need it).

Comment: Question if I don't need any UI capabilities, how much these deter from the main goal?

What I liked about Poco that it provides bare minimum, and while Qt seems certainly more invested, I do prefer something leaner.

Comment: Qt is an integrated solution, even the QtCore package is quite large. If you only want to use small parts of it, it's probably not worth learnign it. If you want a good suggestion though, you should tell us what do you need, not what do you don't need.

Answer (score 4):

Besides POCO and Qt, there are only two other mature cross-platform application frameworks suitable for C++ that come to my mind:
[WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and [gtk+](http://www.gtk.org/) (or its C++ binding [gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/)).